# How to add an additional network interface on a KVM vm?

Tags: linux, network-interface

Learning how to manage networks and use NIC bonding. I'm trying to figure out how to go about adding an additional virtual network interface to my KVM vm

```
[root@RHEL8 ~]# ifconfig
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.122.34  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe3b:d185  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 52:54:00:3b:d1:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Desired end result would be to have **two enp** interfaces.

Comment: Depends on how you set the VM up: Plain QEMU command, virsh, virt-manager (the GUI app).

Comment: I have been using the virsh command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your vm's conf,

```
sudo virsh edit VMname
```

and add

```
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="00:00:00:00:00:00"/>  # Give it some MAC address
      <source network="link-local"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>  # bus 0x02 since it's 2nd
    </interface>
```

Since you apparently use RHEL8, `virtio` type should have available kernel modules. You could try  `<model type="e1000e"/>` for a slower but more supported type.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a bridge on your host. The following command will add a tun/tap backend network interface to your VM.

```
virsh attach-interface --type bridge --source $YOUR_HOST_BRIDGE --model virtio $YOUR_VM
```